# Problems calling EJB from a Standalone client in EAP 7

Tags: jboss, migration, jboss7.x, weblogic12c

I migrated Weblogin application to JBoss EAP 7.1.

But when I call my API from browser I have an exception :

> WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public abstract java.util.List
>   com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.hcp.service.UserService.getCountryLanguages(java.lang.String,com.medtronic.diabetes.carelink.hcp.persistence.model.ApplicationType)
>   of bean: UserServiceImpl is not allowed

UserService method signature :

```
@PermitAll
    List<LanguageDefinitionItemDto> getCountryLanguages(String countryCode, ApplicationType type);
```

In weblogic.xml I had security properties:

```
  <security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <principal-name>adminGroup</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>

<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <principal-name>userGroup</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>

<!-- session configuration -->
<session-descriptor>
    <cookie-secure> true </cookie-secure>
    <persistent-store-type> replicated_if_clustered </persistent-store-type>
    <cookie-http-only> false </cookie-http-only>
    <url-rewriting-enabled> false </url-rewriting-enabled>
    <timeout-secs> 1800 </timeout-secs>
</session-descriptor>
```

in standalone-full.xml I have one login-module from another ear. Do I need to add RoleMappingLoginModule ?

```
   <security-domain name="mySecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/jdbc/powds"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password FROM DDMS_ACCOUNT WHERE user_name = ?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT group_name, 'Roles' FROM DDMS_ACCOUNT_GRP_ASSOC WHERE user_name = ?"/>
                        </login-module>           
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
```

Plese help me to transfer this config on Jboss EAP 7.1.0.

I tried add in web.xml but this didn't help :

```
 <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

jboss server.log

```
Principal: anonymous
:callerRunAs=null:callerRunAs=null:ejbRestrictionEnforcement=false:ejbVersion=2.0];Action=authorization;Source=org.jboss.security.plugins.javaee.EJBAuthorizationHelper;policyRegistration=null;Exception:=PBOX00017: Access denied: authorization failed ;
2019-12-17 10:59:59,177 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-7) PBOX00354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
```

If I remove @PermitAll annotation it still doesnt works.

End please explain me where this **security-role** uses and why?  Do I need to add this admin and user to jboss security ApplicationRealm?

`<default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="false"/>` works. but  Will it have negative affect?

Answer (score 0):

delete cofig  `<default-security-domain value="other"/>`  in  standalone-full.xml helped me